# Model Binding object and collection of object to a given route

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have to support a protocol that works such that both a single object and a collection of the same type of objects can be POST'ed to a given endpoint for creation.

E.g.

```
POST /api/Foos
{id: 123, foo: 'bar'}

POST /api/Foos
[{id: 123, foo: 'bar'}, {id: 456, foo: 'baz'}]
```

I was thinking I could do something similar to this:

```
class FooController : ApiController
{
     public IHttpActionResult PostSingle(FooModel model) { ... whatever }
     public IHttpActionResult PostCollection(IEnumerable<FooModel> models) { ... }
}
```

Admittedly I haven't tried it yet but I'm guessing there's more I'll have to do to get it working.

Question: what is the best way to bind a POST action to accept both a single object and a collection of the same type of object?

Comment: More than 2 years after, still interested in the answer :)